# How to get facebook sign on approved for site before site is live?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook Sign On for a site requires approval from FB. However, if we want to implement this before a particular site is "live", how do we do so? Is there a "light" way to implement sign on that doesn't require the same level of approval?

Comment: Simple login itself does not require review, as long as you are asking users for only the three basic permissions.

Comment: Ah yes that will do it -- I'll let you create an answer out of this if you like so I can accept it. It's a work around, but because the basic permissions (public_profile, email, and user_friends) will work at least initially, it's a good solution for us.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, so I'm going to do my best to answer based on what I *think* you're asking.

If you're referring to Facebook login for your app, it shouldn't require approval from FB.  You will however need to toggle it on for Public use.

To do so, go to 'Manage Apps' under 'Developer' located on the left side of your FB feed.  Next, go to 'My Apps' > 'Status & Review' > It will ask you if you want to make your app and it's features available to the public, that option needs to be toggled to 'Yes'.

If your website isn't live yet, but you still want to test Facebook login, you can set your OAuth Redirect to local host.  This can be set in 'Settings' > 'OAuth Settings'.

Hope that is helpful.  If neither is what you're asking, feel free to clarify and I'll provide additional answers if I'm able.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. CBroe helped steer me in the right direction with respect to basic vs. review-required permissions. I still found the OAuth Settings useful, though.